# GridGain. Local node's library list differs from remote node's, leveldbjni-all-1.1.jar

Tags: eclipse, gridgain

When I try to use gridGain on one machine, I run a ggstart.bat and run app on eclipse, I added all .jar files from gridGain sourсe folder, but I see on console this when start:


```
Local node's library list differs from remote node's

<leveldbjni-all-1.1.jar> vs. <not found>
```


(in ecsiple's console conversely - not found vs level...)
Only this file from all, I try delete this, in doesn't work, try to rename, message change to <newFile> vs. <not found>
I try to found about this file, found only "download leveldbjni-all-1.1.jar" and something different size of file, but no about this file.

---

May be someone knows how to fix it or something about this file?
Version of gridGain is 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The jar your are talking about is a [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) library, used in one of GridGain swapspace implementations. Please check if you are running the same version of GridGain remotely and from Eclipse, and that the classpath is equal.